# How to get user interests from the native iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been reading through the documentation, and I couldn't find anything. For other properties like name, id, etc, they're available in the FBGraphUser class. What I need though is the interest list for the user. I believe I have to use the FBGraphObject class, but I'm not really sure how to go about doing so. Any guidance would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of me/interests ?

Comment: I'm looking for a native method of some sort through the Objective-C library that does this.

Comment: Could you provide more info on what you mean by interest list, i.e. what would be the equivalent call if you made a Graph API call say using the Graph API explorer?

Comment: It's pretty much what you said earlier. /friend_id/interests/access_id

Comment: Find any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

me/interests  is how you get the interests of the user.  if you're looking for someone else, like the user's friend, then id/interests

This counts on the user being signed in

```
-(void)fbRequest{

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/interests" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *result,NSError *error){

        if(!error){
            NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            [self updateInterests:data];


        }else{

        }
    }];
}


-(void)updateInterests:(NSArray*)interests
{
NSString *str = self.groupList.text;

for(FBGraphObject <FBGraphUser>*interest in interests) //Using FBGraphUser because it implements name though I'd love to use something else
{

    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",interest.name ];
}
[self.groupList setText:str];

}
```

an alternative to the above method does not rely on the coincidence that graphuser has name, so here it is

```
-(void)updateInterests:(NSArray*)interests
{
NSString *str = self.groupList.text;

for(FBGraphObject *interest in interests) //Using FBGraphUser because it implements name though I'd love to use something else
{

    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[interest objectForKey:@"name"] ];
}
[self.groupList setText:str];

}
```

Comment: Note:  self.groupList is just a uiLabel.

Comment: me/interests not work now? do you have any alternate solution for the same issue

Comment: I actually just ran me/interests up against the 2.1 api in the graph explorer and obtained results... 

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

please check up against the explorer and confirm your issue.